# PHP passing URL parameters best practice

Tags: php

I have a search page that outputs search results. You can filter results based on on the following criteria before running the search.

```
1. status 
2. order by
3. record type
```

Viewing a record redirects the user to the edit form page and if they click the cancel button they redirect back to the search results.

Here's what I've done:

1. I stored the GET parameters (status,order_by and record_type)  in session variables
2. When the user clicks cancel on the edit form, I use the session variables to redirect back to the search results as follows:

   if (@$_POST['cancelbtn']){

   ```
       if (isset($_SESSION['searchForm'])){
               header("location:searchForm.php?products=".$_SESSION['product']."&ticket_status=".$_SESSION['status']."&order_by=".$_SESSION['order_by']."&record_type=".$_SESSION['record_type']."&searchbtn=Go!");
       }
   ```

   }

The above works for me but I'd like to know if this is the best way to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a *bad* way of doing it, but I would try and future proof it a bit. Instead of storing each individual variable in the session, try storing the URL. That way, if you change your search form to have some additional parameters, you won't need to change much of your code.

```
//Your search results page
$_SESSION['searchResults'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//Your form page
if (array_key_exists('cancelButton', $_POST) {
    header('Location: '.$_SESSION['searchResults']);
    exit;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: cheers, thats the kinda thing i was looking for. Will test it and get back.